# Last login: Tue Mar 7 11:03:23 on ttys001 The file /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app does not exist. [Eugene@MacBook-Pro ~ ]$

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

**Problem:**
Every time I open the terminal IntelliJ starts with it. I uninstalled IntelliJ and I keep getting this message in my terminal. I am trying to get rid of this message from popping up in my terminal.

```
    Last login: Tue Mar  7 10:32:37 on ttys002
The file /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app does not exist.
```

**What I've tried:** I am currently using zsh (oh-my-zsh) as a shell for my terminal on my Mac OS. I tried checking the .zshrc file and I might be looking in the wrong place. I tried manually searching usr and bin files but came up empty.

Comment: Did you check the shell startup files in your home directory?

Comment: I believe I have. I only see the .zshrc file. I do not have bash_profile, bash_login, or profile file.

Comment: Please check the Terminal application [startup preferences](https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/359/terminal.png).

Comment: I do have it as Default Login Shell. The complete path is /bin/zsh. Everything is else is set to default.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have other ideas then, maybe some zsh expert will chime in to help.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for trying =)

Answer (score 0):

This was a hacky way to fix this but the problem was the /usr/local/bin/zsh file.
I just commented this out and it worked! 
My guess is that RUN_PATH, CONFIG_PATH, SYSTEM_PATH was configured in a way to open IntelliJ every time I opened the terminal.